# Why can't I concatenate and print the value returned by a function?

Tags: perl, return-value, function-call

I have a Perl program that calls a function, in this case `ref`, and checks the result. Specifically, I am testing that a variable is a hash reference. In that case, `ref` will return `'HASH'`. I tested it and it worked.

Then I decided to log it, adding a `print` that displays the result of the same call, but it didn't work correctly. Here is a reduced version:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $book_ref = {};
$book_ref->{'title'} = 'The Lord of the Rings';

if (ref $book_ref eq 'HASH') {
    print "ref \$book_ref is a " . ref $book_ref . "\n";
}

print "Program is over\n";
```

To my surprise, this was the output:

```
ref $book_ref is a Program is over
```

And despite using `strict` and `warnings` there were neither errors nor warnings.
The call to `ref` is exactly the same (it's a copy and paste), but while it works correctly inside the `if` condition, `print` doesn't display anything, and actually seems to be interrupted, as the newline character is clearly skipped. Why does the behaviour change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that the function `ref` is called without parentheses, and this causes the line to be parsed incorrectly.

- When `ref` is called inside the `if`, the condition is clearly delimited by parentheses, which means that `ref` knows perfectly well what its argument is: `$book_ref`. There's no ambiguity.
- Instead, when printing the result, the lack of parentheses means that Perl will parse the line in a way that was not intended:

  1. First it will concatenate `$book_ref` and `"\n"`. In scalar context, `$book_ref` evaluates to a string like `HASH(0x1cbef70)`, therefore the result is the string `"HASH(0x1cbef70)\n"`
  2. Then, `ref` will be called on the string `"HASH(0x1cbef70)\n"`, [producing as output an empty string](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#ref-EXPR): `''`.
  3. At this point, `print` prints the empty string, that is, nothing, and stops there. The newline character `\n` is skipped because it has already been consumed by `ref`, so `print` doesn't even see it. And there are no errors.

All of this descends from [Perl's operator precedence](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity): from the table,

```
(...)

 8.    left         + - .
 9.    left         << >>
10.    nonassoc     named unary operators
11.    nonassoc     < > <= >= lt gt le ge
12.    nonassoc     == != <=> eq ne cmp ~~

(...)
```

where the "function call" is actually a "named unary operator" (the unary operator being `ref`). So the `.` operator at line 8 has higher precedence than the function call at line 10, which is why the result of `print` is not the expected one. On the other hand, the function call has higher precedence than `eq` (at line 12), which is why inside the `if` everything works as expected.

The solution to precedence problems is to use .

- A possibility is to use parentheses to emphasize the function call:

  ```
  print "ref \$book_ref is a " . ref($book_ref) . "\n";
  ```
- Another one, which I like less but nevertheless works, is to use parentheses to isolate the string that must be concatenated, by putting the opening bracket just before `ref`:

  ```
  print "ref \$book_ref is a " . (ref $book_ref) . "\n";
  ```
- Another possible approach, suggested by zdim in a comment, is to use commas:

  ```
  print "ref \$book_ref is a ", ref $book_ref, "\n";
  ```

When I first wrote the `if` I decided to avoid the parentheses to make the code more readable. Then I copied it and didn't notice the problem. I ended up wasting 2 hours to find the bug.

The best solution seems to be the first one, because if you copy it to another place (like another `print`) you are guaranteed to also copy the parentheses that prevent the problem. With the second one I probably wouldn't realize how important the parentheses are and wouldn't copy them. And the third one works only if you remember that you have to always use commas and not dots, which is not obvious and therefore error prone. So, although they work, I consider them less safe.

Other comments have also suggested to use `printf`, which requires dealing with format specifiers, or expression interpolation, like `print "ref \$book_ref is a ${\ ref $book_ref }\n";`, which I find harder to read.

Bottom line: **always use the parentheses**.

Comment: Or use commas, `print "value is ", (code), "\n"`, by [print LIST](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html)

Comment: Or use expression interpolation: `print "ref \$book_ref is a ${\ ref $book_ref }\n"`